# Magento 2 problem in admin login

Tags: magento2, wamp

I have sucessfully installed magento2 but I cannot login to admin, I saw the related question and the problem was rewrite_module
I already enabled rewrite_module as checked in wamp  and i am seeing it as a loaded module in phpinfo
also I removed the hashtag # in the httpd.conf for this module to be loaded
I don't know how to resolve the issue

before, in previous versions I would do something with sessions and I could see the admin panel but I don't know here we would have the same approach or i am missing something

when I go to homepage it doesn't have any styles but I can see the details and text stuff and logo.

Comment: Can you post any error logs?  Are you running on windows?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1180#issuecomment-91129920 you can see my question which has not an answer yet here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there are issues with static files.  Without error logs it is hard to say for sure, but it might be an issue with symlinks.

The following is taken from https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/64808/594

When not in production mode Magento 2 will try to create symlinks for some static resources.  You can change that behavior by doing the following.

1. Open up `app/etc/di.xml` and find the `virtualType name="developerMaterialization"` section.
   In that section you'll find an item `name="view_preprocessed"` that needs to be modified or deleted. You can modify it by changing the contents from `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink` to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`
2. Delete the files under pub/static to get rid of any existing symlinks.  You may want to be careful not to delete the `.htaccess` file.

This should solve your error with the symlink.