# Unable to login first time to admin after installing Magento2

Tags: magento2

New installation of Magento2 on Ubuntu, the homepage and admin page loads, but doesn't accept the user/pass entered. There's no error message displayed either. Tried:

- different browsers, clearing cache & cookies
- timezone is correctly set on server.
- resetting password directly from db

  UPDATE `admin_user` SET `password` = MD5('NEWPASSWORD') WHERE `username` = 'ADMINUSERNAME';

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need update and set `lock_expires` as `null` and try again.

Comment: Hi @Bill, it is already at NULL

Comment: Can you show screen shot ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-1tSR-v8mqBS3dVa0gyZml5RU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Plz try this link, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63117/magento-2-problem-in-admin-login

Answer (score 1):

Looks like cookies cannot be set and thus admin session cannot be started. If base URL is set to `localhost` (`http://localhost/admin`) cookies won't work. Reinstall Magento using virtual host or at least `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Hi Alex, the base url was set to http://nfcshop.ca/ and we're using virtual host. The database is external, but we didn't get any error messages during install and admin credentials were actually saved to the db.

Where else can I ensure cookies are set?

Comment: Are you able to create customer account on the store front and log in using that account?

Comment: Hi Alex, looks like your on to something here. 

Because no, creating an account from the home page doesn't seem to work either. Just brings me to the Login or Register new account page.

Comment: Try to debug to understand if PHP can actually start a session.